# Stylelint skips entire folders

Tags: javascript, macos, yarnpkg, stylelint

I have stylelint installed in my project, and I've configured its configuration.
I added a script to run this linter on my `src` folder.

For some reason, the linter scans only one folder.

Here is my configuration file stylelint.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    extends: [
        'stylelint-config-standard-scss',
        'stylelint-config-prettier-scss',
        'stylelint-config-recess-order',
    ],
    plugins: ['stylelint-scss', 'stylelint-order'],
    rules: {
        'selector-class-pattern': [
            '^[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*((--([a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)(__([a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*))?)|(__([a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)(--([a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*))?))?$',
            { resolveNestedSelectors: true, message: 'Expected class selector to be camel case' },
        ],
        'value-no-vendor-prefix': null,
        'selector-id-pattern': null,

        'scss/at-import-partial-extension': null,
    },
};
```

This is the script: `"stylelint": "stylelint --f verbose src/**/*.scss",`

My src folder has a lot of .scss files. But this script only scans 2 files for some reason.

```
$ stylelint --f verbose src/**/*.scss

2 sources checked
 /Users/amir/Desktop/Development/Vinyl projects/LandingPag-REAL/src/styles/custom.scss
 /Users/amir/Desktop/Development/Vinyl projects/LandingPag-REAL/src/styles/variables.scss

0 problems found

✨  Done in 0.79s.
```

Why would it ignores all other files? I don't have some "ignore" configuration file.

**NOTE: It worked on Windows perfect (didn't skip), on Mac it skips almost the entire src file**

Also when I change the script to run `stylelint ... **/*.scss` it does work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [quote your input glob](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/usage/cli#usage-examples), otherwise the shell (which differs on Windows and Mac) will interpret it rather than Stylelint itself.

If you're only targeting *nix, you can use single quotes:

```
"stylelint": "stylelint --f verbose 'src/**/*.scss'",
```

For cross-platform use escaped double quotes:

```
"stylelint": "stylelint --f verbose \"src/**/*.scss\"",
```

---

Incidentally, you:

- can remove the `plugins` property as both plugins are bundled in their respective configs
- should put the prettier config last so that it overrides everything before

```
{
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss",
    "stylelint-config-recess-order",
    "stylelint-config-prettier-scss"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "selector-class-pattern": [
      "^[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*((--([a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)(__([a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*))?)|(__([a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)(--([a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*))?))?$",
      {
        "resolveNestedSelectors": true,
        "message": "Expected class selector to be camel case"
      }
    ],
    "value-no-vendor-prefix": null,
    "selector-id-pattern": null,

    "scss/at-import-partial-extension": null
  }
}
```